# My kivy program always rotate screen on android

Tags: android, python, kivy

Recently I tried kivy, but I meet several problems. Thanks for help.

First, my kivy program always rotates screen when running on android. Usually the status bar on android is on the top, when I run kivy it goes to the right side.

Screen rotation is enabled on my android, but when I rotate my phone, the direction of kivy program doesn't change.

And I also try to rotate window by Window.rotation = 90, but the position of status bar didn't change.

The program is very simple:

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
class PongGame(Widget):
    pass


class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return PongGame()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

pong.kv:

```
<PongGame>:    
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x - 5, 0
            size: 10, self.height

    Label:
        font_size: 70  
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"

    Label:
        font_size: 70  
        center_x: root.width * 3 / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> First, my kivy program always rotates screen when running on android. Usually the status bar on android is on the top, when I run kivy it goes to the right side.

This is an option in the `buildozer.spec`, just change the orientation line to `orientation = all`. You can also read the comments on all the other lines to see the other options.

You can also set many more orientation options (including e.g. optionally obeying the user's system settings etc) by calling the android api directly with pyjnius. I have some example code for this [here](https://github.com/inclement/pyjnius-api-wrappers/blob/master/orientation.py). Something similar will probably go in [plyer](https://github.com/kivy/plyer).

If you're using python-for-android directly, the orientation option is one of the command line arguments you can pass to build.py. I don't remember offhand but you can check the documentation - though I recommend using buildozer anyway.